# Router in Django REST Framework with viewset queryset filter

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want to do data filtering in a api response. Ie make such addresses

```
/api/v1//CoinCost?coin_id=coin_name&dateStart=2020-02-06T00:00:00&dateEnd=2020-02-08T00:00:00
```

My code now:

```
    from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class CoinCostFilterSet(filters.FilterSet)
    class Meta:
        model = CoinCost
        fields = {
            'coin_id': ['exact'],
            'timestamp': ['gt', 'lt'],
        }

class CoinCostViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = CoinCost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CoinCostsSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = CoinCostFilterSet
```

And my urls.py. This url no work

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from .views import CoinsView, CoinsCostsView, CoinCostViewSet
from django.views import generic

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('CoinCost/$', CoinCostViewSet, basename='Coins')

app_name = 'Coins'

urlpatterns = [
    path('coins/', CoinsView.as_view()),
    path('coins_costs/update/', views.coins_costs_load),
    path('coins_load/update/', views.coins_load),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    ]
```

i try /api/v1/CoinCost?coin_id=bulbacoin and i see errors

```
Using the URLconf defined in myminter.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
api/v1/ coins/
api/v1/ coins_costs/update/
api/v1/ coins_load/update/
api/v1/ ^$ [name='api-root']
api/v1/ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
The current path, api/v1/CoinCost/, didn't match any of these.
```

Why does my router not work and how to make a working router? Thanks!

Comment: there should not be any double slash in url in the first place

Comment: Hey. This is a typo of course, on the site I do not double slash. That is not the problem.

Comment: Please add all your `urls.py` file

Comment: are you sure that the urls.py you are using being imported in root urls.py(which resides beside manage.py)?

Comment: All urls.py is added.

Comment: Yes. Other url is work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line:

```py
router.register('CoinCost/$', CoinCostViewSet, basename='Coins')
```

To be like so:

```py
router.register('CoinCost', CoinCostViewSet, basename='Coins')
```

Also, note that you have no views in your `CoinCostViewSet`, so either add actions or use a class like `viewsets.ModelViewSet`:

```py
class CoinCostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CoinCost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CoinCostsSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = CoinCostFilterSet
```

Comment: Thanks, I used such url too, and others, tried many options. What views are needed in my example? I do not get you..

Comment: @Igor Check out the [Django REST Framework Viewsets documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/). If you extend the `viewsets.ViewSet` class then you need to implement at least one [action](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions), e.g: `list`, `create`, `retrieve`, `update`. You can also use other classes and/or mixins that implement the logic for you, e.g: [`ModelViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I read it many times, but for example, what do I need to write in the def list in order for the filter to work? You can write an example of  my CoinCostViewSet ?